# How to use local wsdl file in generated service code (jax-ws)

Tags: java, web-services, jax-ws

It generates URL with http code, how do I change it to local file so that later
web services could be packed to jar and this jar will be used as library.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The generated service class has a constructor that takes a `URL` to the WSDL. Use that to point the service client to a different WSDL. See the default constructor of that class in case you don't know what to provide as `QName`.